# image won't show in Eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a folder containing images under WebContent. If I copy `file 1.jpg` to images using Windows Explorer, it won't show on my webpage:

```
document.getelementById("image1").src = "./images/1.jpg"
```

However, if I right click the project in Eclipse, refresh, then everything works.

How do I remove the need to refresh the project? The images are supposed to be generated by another program dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If something outside of Eclipse modifies the workspace it is always necessary to do a refresh.

However you can configure Eclipse to do this automatically in Preferences > General > Workspace. Check the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' option.

If the program generating the images is an Eclipse plugin it can use Eclipse APIs to create the files or do the refresh (a normal program cannot do this).

If you run the program using Eclipse Run External Tool configuration there is a Refresh tab that will let you set up the refresh to do when the program terminates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What happens if I run my web app outside Eclipse (in standalone Tomcat)? Will any newly added images be able to be displayed properly?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what happens in that case